# Склонение фамилий

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте. Как просклонять фамилию Быба? Пример (семья ивановых). Какое будет окончание в случае с фамилией Быба?

Answer (score 3):

Фамилия какая? Семья какая? Быба. К фамилии какой? Семье какой? Быба. О фамилии какой? О семье какой? Быба. Несогласованное определение, не склоняется.

Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное *а* после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т. д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)

Александру Быбе, Ирине Быбе.

Примечание. В справочной литературе отмечаются колебания при употреблении грузинских и японских фамилий на неударную *-а.* В СМИ можно встретить как склоняемые, так и несклоняемые варианты: песни Окуджавы, приезд премьера Накагава, творчество Акиры Куросавы. Следует отметить, что отмеченная тенденция к изменению этих фамилий позволяет рекомендовать склонять их. Финские фамилии в силу их трудного произношения рекомендуют не склонять: исследователь Яакко Лаллукка – работы Яакко Лаллукка, студент Юхо Ранта – справка для Юхо Ранта.

Вы происхождение фамилии знаете? Если славянская или романская - склоняется. Если она от прозвища-звукоподражания "бы-ба", то чаще не склоняется.

Comment: Происхождения не знаю. Думаю что белорусская фамилия.

Comment: Значит,склоняется

Comment: Это должно быть западноукраинская фамилия, от венгерского Бибо (см. Иштван Бибо), в более частом украинском варианте - Биба. Известный носитель - Андрей Биба, футболист киевского Динамо 60-х годов.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

А музыкант "Быба" - это прозвище. По паспорту он Александр Быбочкин. Я лично такого вообще не знаю, но это по источникам.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос!

Вообще для фамилий отличных от правильных русских притяжательнвых на -ов, -ин и -ский (Иванов, Фомин, Петровский) множественное число не образуется или имеет ограниченное употребление. Поэтому - **семья Быба**.
Но лучше все-таки воздержаться по возможности от использования такого оборота вообще. Ибо по такой форме не очень уверенно восстанавливается исходная.

Comment: А в остальных случаях эта фамилия склоняется?

Comment: В остальных случаях, т.е. в единственном числе - да, по общему правилу. Фамилии на -А (кроме французских) всегда склоняются, независимо от места ударения, причем и в мужском, и в женском варианте. 

Насчет "несогласованного определения" у Людмилы. Это не так, потому что грамматика требует вообще не согласования, а управления (семья - чья? - Ивановых). Аналогично "Петр и Мария Ивановы", "пошел к Ивановым", "в гостях у Ивановых".

Comment: И только там, где употребления множественного числа в принципе невозможно или затруднено, используется форма единственного числа.
"Петр и Мария Быба", "пошел к Быба", "в гостях у Быба" (подразумевается пара)

В этих примерах множественная форма возможна, но не слишком распространена. Вообще вопрос о множественной форме фамилий благополучно обходят во всех истониках, ограничиваясь упоминанием вариативности по классическому примеру: "братья Гримм, но братья Гонкуры". Других объяснений, кроме закрепленной традиции, тут нет.

Comment: behemothus, что значит "Насчет "несогласованного определения"... Это не так, потому что грамматика требует вообще не согласования, а управления"? Мы говорим о разных вещах -  Вы о виде связи в словосочетании, а я о члене предложения - несогласованном определении, и это именно так,несогласованное определение связано в словосочетании как раз по типу управления. Любите Вы поспорить, не вникнув в суть.

Comment: Людмила, а в чем суть, в которую я якобы не вник?  
Давайте от печки. Семья Ивановых - это тоже "несогласованное определение"?