# Склонение фамилии Купава

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Фамилия нашей семьи Купава. Свекор со свекровью сказали, что фамилия наша не склоняется. Сейчас дочь пошла в школу и встал вопрос о падежах при подписывании тетрадей... Учитель утверждает, что фамилия склоняется по падежом. Согласно приведенному правилу выше... Вроде они правы, но хотелось бы узнать это точно. Что прописано в специальном словаре фамилий?  Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Согласно приведённому правилу выше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фамилия склоняемая, но не совсем по правилам, касающимся неударного *-а* после согласных.

Она представляет собой существительное!

В пункте [13.1.13. Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/71-rubric-482) подобные фамилии названы нестандартными и рассмотрены примеры с *Зима, Зозуля*...

Проблема возникает не при изменении по падежам, а при образовании множественного числа:

*Повстречался с семейством Купав? Скучаю по всем Купавам?*

> ...Представляет интерес вопрос об образовании множественного числа от
>   склоняемых фамилий на -а (-я). В грамматическом приложении к
>   «Справочнику личных имен народов РСФСР» такие фамилии квалифицированы
>   как нестандартные и ***для них рекомендуется в качестве нормы
>   употребление во множественном числе для всех падежей формы,
>   совпадающей с исходной***.

Comment: *Фамилия склоняемая, но не совсем по правилам,* - и в чем Вы видите отступление от правил? Фамилия-существительное - дело весьма обычное и склоняются они по обычным правилам, как и все существительные. Что до множественного числа, то это весьма и весьма спорная рекомендация. Возможно в вашем варианте это и проходит, и то только потому, что есть родовое слово. А если "повстречался со всеми *Купава*?  Ясно же, что "со всеми Купавами".

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите ответ Людмилы в [этом вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29794/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9). Процитирую основное: "Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению..." Это относится и к мужчинам с такими фамилиями, и к женщинам: "Александру Быбе, Ирине Быбе".

В Вашем случае учитель прав, фамилия склоняется.

Answer (score 2):

Тут и обсуждать нечего. Фамилия склонятся, как и все фамилии на -а/-я (за исключением очень небольшого числа иноязычных). Источников вам сейчас накидают кучу, не сомневаюсь, что все будут утверждать одно и то же. Что вы называете "специальным словарем фамилий", не очень понятно. Мне известно несколько разного рода словарей фамилий, в основном они посвящены происхождению, ни один из них не фиксирует какие-то правила склонений.

Тут более интересно мнение ваших свекра и свекрови. Утверждение носителей, что конкретная фамилия не склоняется, вообще-то дело довольно частое. Оно крайне редко оказывается значимым для всякого рода паспортисток и работников ЗАГСов. Строго говоря мне известны лишь единичные случаи узаконения отклонений от общих правил склонения фамилий. К таковым относятся:

-неблагозвучность при склонении: Скобец-Скобеца при общей норме "Cкобца",
-нераспознаваемость исходного варианта: например, односложные фамилии типа Ба не склоняются вопреки общим нормам,
- фонетическая сложность при склонении: Лец - Леца, при норме Льца и некоторые другие), 
-трудности установления типа склонения: Гурцкая - рекомендуется не склонять, ибо часто используемое cклонение по русскому типу Гурцкая-Гурцкой-Гурцкую не соответcтвует грузинскому (мегрельскому) происхождению фамилии, а нормативное Гурцкая-Гурцкаи-Гурцкае-Гурцкаей бесконечно трудно воспринимается.

По сути дела в этом списке всего два уникальных основания: фонетическое и смысловое. И это, наверное, исчерпывающий перечень. Хотя когда-то я насчитывал до семи подобных причин, но часть из них оказалась не исключениями, а частными случаями правил, а часть - совсем уж экзотическими случаями, не находящими подтверждения.

В любом случае такой простой и прекрасной русской фамилии как Купава нет никакого основания отказывать в праве на склонение по общим правилам.